# Imputation with MICE biased under MCAR in extreme case of missingness

Tags: r, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

I am currently using mice package to impute missing values for a simulation project. I use different performance metrics (eg. bias, precision etc) to compare different methods(eg. complete cases, single imputation methods, multiple imputation) on how to deal with missing values under different scenarios.

I am bit puzzled with some results I came across and I would like some help to understand what is happening.

In a nutshell: I simulate n datasets drawn from the original complete dataset and I introduce NAs completely at random. Under MCAR, I expect (for example) the complete cases analysis to provide me with an unbiased estimate of the quantity I am interested in(will be defined below). Af far as my understanding goes, I expect the same to happen using mice.
Under an extreme scenario of missingness, mice is producing a biased estimate.

I cannot share any of the data but I will provide a reproducible example below with the simulation setup.

Please see comments within code chunk to better understand:

```
library(mice)
library(data.table)
set.seed(1500)

# Dataset to use
data(iris);setDT(iris)

# Remove Species. Not needed
iris[, Species := NULL]

# The quantity I am interested in is simply the average of all numerical columns
# in the iris dataset. Lets call it "Score". The average of this Score 
# across nsim would be the parameter I want to estimate.
iris[, Score := rowMeans(iris)]

# Number of simulated datasets
nsim <- 2000

# Size of simulated datasets to be drawn from the original complete iris df
df_size <- 100

# Percent of missingness
n_miss <- 40

# Lets draw the indeces from the original complete dataset to be used
samples <- list()
for (i in 1:nsim){
  samples[[i]] <- sample(1:nrow(iris),
                         df_size,
                         replace = TRUE)}

# Realize the dataframes
frames <- lapply(X = samples, function(x){ iris[x, ]})
```

I now have the simulated datasets (frames) drawn from the original complete iris dataset.
It's time to introduce an extreme case of missingness. All four columns of the simulated datasets
are missing completely at random. I understand this is an extreme case, and normally
would not proceed like that but I want
to see how the mice imputation will behave under that scenario.

```
samples_NA <- list()
for (i in 1:nsim){
  tmp <- frames[[i]]
  tmp[sample(x = 1:nrow(tmp), n_miss), ] <- NA
  # tmp[sample(x = 1:nrow(tmp), 40), Sepal.Length:= NA]
  tmp[, Score := NULL]
  samples_NA[[i]] <- tmp
}
```

```
# Function to use within the pool function of mice
calc_score <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4) {
  score <- (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)/4
  fit <- lm(score ~ 1)
}


# Mice imputation, settings default
theta_i_imp <- c()
i <-1
for (i in 1:length(samples_NA)){
  
  tmp <- copy(samples_NA[[i]])
  # default mice settings
  x_imp <- mice(tmp,
                printFlag = F)
  
  fit <- with(x_imp, calc_score(x1 = Sepal.Length,
                                x2 = Sepal.Width,
                                x3 = Petal.Length,
                                x4 = Petal.Width))
  pooled <- pool(fit)
  theta_i_imp[i] <- pooled$pooled$estimate
  print(i)
}
```

Based on Morris et al. (2019) I will calculate the estimated bias of the expected score across simulations and the Monte Carlo Standard error as well as the bias CIs.
[image]

```
bias_imp <- sum(theta_i_imp-mean(iris$Score))/nsim
bias_imp_SE <- sqrt(sum((theta_i_imp - mean(theta_i_imp))^2) / (nsim*(nsim-1)))
high_imp <- bias_imp + 1.96*bias_imp_SE
low_imp <- bias_imp - 1.96*bias_imp_SE
print(data.frame(low_imp, bias_imp, high_imp))
     low_imp   bias_imp   high_imp
1 0.02747278 0.03218902 0.03690527
```

And just for illustration I will do the same for the complete case analysis.

```
theta_i_complete <- c()
i <-1
for (i in 1:length(samples_NA)){
  
  tmp <- samples_NA[[i]]
  tmp <- na.omit(tmp)
  tmp[, Score := rowMeans(tmp)]
  theta_i_complete[i] <- mean(tmp$Score)
  print(i)
  
}
```

```
bias_complete <- sum(theta_i_complete-mean(iris$Score))/nsim
bias_complete_SE <- sqrt(sum((theta_i_complete - mean(theta_i_complete))^2) / (nsim*(nsim-1)))
high_complete <- bias_complete + 1.96*bias_complete_SE
low_complete <- bias_complete - 1.96*bias_complete_SE
print(data.frame(low_complete, bias_complete, high_complete))
  low_complete bias_complete high_complete
1  -0.00731813  -0.002966458   0.001385213
```

As you can see based on the code above, complete cases analysis produces an unbiased estimate for the expected "Score" as expected under MCAR, while mice is producing a biased one.

Any thoughts on these results? Am I thinking this wrong or do I have a mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance,

Chris